# How to Register Broadcast Receiver in MainService

Tags: java, android

hello i want to Register Broadcast Receiver in my app's mainservice but I don't know how that possible nowadays on Android O action USER_PRESENT doesn't work statically registered receiver so that i want to register receiver dynamically in my MainService PLEASE GIVE ME EXAMPLE.

```
package com.system.service;

import android.app.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;

public class MainService extends Service
{
public static void start() {
    try {
        try {
            final Method method =  Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread").getMethod("currentApplication", (Class<?>[])new Class[0]);
            final Context context = (Context)method.invoke(null, (Object[])null);
            if (context == null) {
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post((Runnable)new c(method));
            }
            else {
                startService(context);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex2) {}
}

public static void startService(final Context context) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, (Class)MainService.class));
}

public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int n, final int n2) {
    Star.start((Context)this);
    return 1;
}
```

}

```
package com.system.service;

import android.content.*;

public class MainBroadcastReceiver extends 
BroadcastReceiver
{
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        MainService.startService(context);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You already have a service in which you want to register a broadcast receiver?  Or you want your service to start in response to a broadcast?

Comment: Yeas i have already service but I don't know how to register Broadcast Receiver in MainService

Answer (score 0):

To register a broadcast receiver inside a service, you can simply do the following:

```
public class MainService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("SOME_ACTION"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO
        }
    };
}
```

And since you registered the receiver at runtime (and not via your manifest), it should work with both implicit and explicit broadcasts, even on Android O.

Comment: Hear is my MainService